# 404 Page Not Found codeigniter url - php

Tags: php, codeigniter

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Index';
```

**config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.tabaneshahr.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**controllers/Index.php:**

```
class Index extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $data = array();

        //$this->blade->render('index' , $data );
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

I think everything is ok but this url doesn't not work :

http://tabaneshahr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes

change

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Index';
```

To

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'index';
```

> I would name controller something different my self like to Home might run into issue if have controller named index

Make sure your filename of the controller is like

Filename: Index.php

Comment: @S.M_Emamian  Try naming file and class something different